# What differences would there be between an intelligently designed human and an evolved one?

Tags: creature-design, humans, humanoid

In my world my races (Humans, Elves and Dwarves mainly) are almost intelligently designed (not quite created by a god in their image, but definitely 'created').
And this got me to thinking, are there any major defects in a human that you would expect not to exist if someone (or something) sat down to create the perfect humanoid?

The one that comes to mind for me is the crossing of our wind pipe with our digestive system, but while I know that is the reason why we can choke I'm not sure it's 100% a bad thing as I assume it also allows us to breath through our mouths (which presumably can be beneficial).

**So the question is, are there any obvious ways to improve the basic humanoid body plan?**

By improve I mean it should make some aspect of our bodies work better or remove a flaw (like the windpipe cross over mentioned above).
The changes should also leave a human looking human (so adding wings or extra limbs isn't an improvement).
They should make sense and be feasible (so you can't just add a back up brain or heart if there is no way the body could sustain them).

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question, and unless you can define ‘improve’ it’s also opinion based...

Comment: @JoeBloggs Fair point. I'll try to think of a way to narrow it down / provide more criteria.

Comment: There wouldn't be a waste pipe running through a recreational area

Comment: @Seperatrix that’s only an improvement from a recreational point of view. From a waste management standpoint it’s considerably more efficient!

Comment: Why would you not consider evolution to be intelligent design?

Comment: It´s really hard to define better here, as it is always a trade off. All the answers so far are sacrificing one thing to gain another. You should really tell us what you are optimizing for!

Comment: I think it all depends on what their creator would consider to be an improvement. Maybe their creator is practical and would consider a full-body pelt a good protection from the weather; maybe it is vain and would consider any body hair unsightly. To define what it would consider an improvement, you'd have to tell us what their creator's personality is like.

Comment: @nzaman there's no reason it couldn't be, but unless you assume that every step is guided in some way (which isn't really evolution as we understand it) then you end up with a less than perfect creature due to the path it had to take. I'm wondering if humans hadn't had to take that path whether they would be different.

Comment: Considering long term large scale human behaviour maps almost perfectly to fluid mechanics, probably not

Comment: @RealSubtle  Agreed.  We would need to know how your deities came to be, and what their proclivities are, to answer this question.  Ultimately, there is no cosmic *reason* for us to exist: we just do.

Comment: One of the reasons this question is incredibly broad is that the "perfect creation" can only exist in a "perfect environment."  The moment you let your creation loose in a world with toxins, solar radiation, the tendency to eat/drink/smoke almost anything, etc. you start getting defects and variations that would need constant "correction" to remain "perfect."  Frankly, the only scientists I know who believe they can tell the difference between evolved and intelligent design are those pushing a political and/or personal agenda because both are necessarily efficient.

Comment: It's all about the healing factor, healing factor, healing factor. With a powerful healing factor you wouldn't have disease, you'd have extended lifespan, and increased stamina.

Comment: How about an Insulin system that can actually restore itself, if you remove the exterior stresses that shoved it out of whack in the first place?  How about immune systems that can be calmed down, when they start to overreach and see you own skin or nerves as enemy? How about adding malformed proteins to the enemy-recognition ability of lymphocytes, preventing prion diseases like Alzheimers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Don't bother fixing things that will make no difference for 99% of pop

Many of the previous answers are trying to remove stuff that are not useful. But, they are not really annoying either. **I was never bothered by my caecum, were you?** So if you remove it, you may save some small amount of energy/trouble for the body. But you could also later discover that, in the end, it had some purpose. Above all, you did something that will not make a noticeable difference in most of the cases.

Mostly they are things that are not optimal, but their correction will not make the human more able for anything. **Do you think your life quality would increase significantly if we fix the path of your laryngeal nerve?**

### So what are the major defects in our bodies?

Well, it's what **kills us**. Let’s take the most frequent mortality causes ([in  Europe](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/Causes_of_death_statistics)):

- Heart diseases
- Cerebrovascular diseases
- Cancer (especially respiratory system)

So, if you could enhance humans, increase their resistance to these problems. For instance:

- Stronger heart, maybe duplicated, or able to heal better
- More resistant veins (especially in the brain)
- Some mechanism that can clean the veins from cholesterol and other deposits
- Immune system able to fight cancer
- Make an immune system that would accept transplants more easily
- And so on…

I guess it is less spectacular than removing wise teeth, but **waaay** more useful.

Last idea: remove addictions from humans. They will live longer and better. Tobacco, alcool, games, sugar, money, … Let them enjoy it, but don’t make them need it.

Comment: You mean no more SE addiction?

Comment: Aren't "cancer fighting immune system" and "extra transplant tolerant immune system" mutually exclusive?

Comment: @user28434 Don't know what kind of capability the OP has. Might be compatible with high enough tech/science/writing magic.

Comment: "Last idea: remove addictions from humans." can be problematic. The #1 addiction that (almost) all humans have is for sex. without that addiction, birthrate would plummet. Also many social structures would lose significance, but what does that matter if there are no children.

Comment: @PcMan There is a difference between normal sex life and sex addiction, just like there is a difference between enjoying a cup of wine and being an alcoholic. Sex addiction is a pathology, and not only people suffering from it are reproducing.

Answer (score 15):

### Low hanging fruit

There are several [glaring design errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_poor_design), or "low hanging fruit", to use a bit of managementese, in human anatomy and physiology, which could be immediately corrected by an intelligent designer with minimal side effects. For example:

- Move the photosensitive cells to the correct side of the retina -- for those readers who know about digital photocameras, our retinas work like old-school photographic sensors instead of more modern [back illuminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-illuminated_sensor) sensors.
- Straighten out the path of the [recurrent laryngeal nerve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_laryngeal_nerve); at present it follows a bizarre path which made sense in fish but is totally unsuitable for mammals.
- Repair our defective mechanism for producing vitamin C, and in general reduce (or even eliminate) the number of [essential amino acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_amino_acid).
- Simplify the anatomy of our feet; as it is, our feet have the same structure as our hands, which made sense for quadrumanual monkeys but is overcomplicated for bipedal humans.
- Fix the stupid way that the breathing reflex is triggered; as it is, breathing is triggered not by a lack of oxygen but by an accumulation of carbon dioxide, with the result that we can pass out due to hypoxia without noticing anything amiss.
- Reduce the number of teeth; we have the same number of teeth as the other apes, but they have elongated muzzles whereas our tiny jaws lead to severe overcrowding.

Comment: Speaking of "low hanging fruit", the unprotected position of the testicles, while fine for our quadruped ancestors, is very poorly adapted for an upright stance.

Comment: #5 is how people can die by carbon monoxide or sulfur hexafluoride asphyxiation -- the other (non-carbon-dioxide) gas displaces oxygen, but as we're still able to normally expel the carbon dioxide from our lungs we don't notice anything amiss, then simply pass out from lack of oxygen and, without external intervention, suffocate.

Comment: I'd also add continuously regenerating teeth (a la sharks or alligators), as opposed to simply having a "baby" set and an "adult" set. When the average lifespan of a human was 40 years it was fine, but as we've extended our lifespan, only having two sets of teeth is woefully inadequate in most cases.

Comment: @DoktorJ: Continuously regenerating teeth would be a massive change, but a third set of teeth may be feasible with minimal side effects. I wanted to put it in, but since my knowledge of human anatomy is limited to what I learned in high school a long time ago I was not sure that it could be done with minimal change to the existing system. Anyway, the list given in the linked WP article lists more such misfeatures, for example some our our sinuses drain *upwards*, which is rather silly.

Comment: @DoktorJ, average lifespan is a misleading value without the consideration that the modal age of death was 0. If you survived childhood there was a good chance of making 70.

Comment: @Separatrix this sourced post says no: https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/k4f4k/what_was_the_average_lifespan_of_prehistoric_man/ . I'm not talking like Victorian or even medieval human lifespan, I'm talking prehistoric (back when we were still making significant evolutionary strides)

Comment: "Simplify the anatomy of our feet". yep. And do something about Knees. The current edition of knees are so ridiculous, so vulnerable, and under-engineered for the stresses we put them through. Would help if a damaged knee could *actually* heal, not just sort of bodge itself into an approximation of the right shape, too.

Comment: @PcMan: That's not a low hanging fruit; it's a complex challenge. Mammals cannot heal cartilage *in general*, not specific to knees. [Cartilage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyaline_cartilage) is a really wonderful material, but it lacks any mechanism of regeneration.

Answer (score 5):

Look into childbirth. It is a very risky process. Any proper design would not risk both the mother and child during the reproductive stage.

A really simple (to describe) change could be to have your fantasy races be egg layers. Egg laying is less risky because of the size/shape consistency of the egg compared to a live birth.

There's an interesting fluff piece here [On Animal Births](http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/explainer/2012/09/animals_giving_birth_dolphins_bear_newborns_easily_but_hyenas_risk_death_.html). A lot of lower risk birthing comes down to adult/offspring size ratios.

Seahorses move the eggs to the father. I don't know a huge amount of the detail, but possibly "birth" is easier for the male as they eggs are in a more "external" area.

Many types of fish lay unfertilised eggs, which a male adds sperm to outside of a female. This means there's no risk to the parents, although the offspring are subject to predation unless looked after.

Comment: Hmmm, that's an excellent point. Not sure what exactly you could change though.

Comment: Also if you could provide a bit more detail of what you could actually change to improve the situation that would help.

Comment: That depends on the scope of your story. Egg laying might be a "simple" change. There's no reason your fantasy races have to be mammals given they are created.

You could also consider something more extreme like recombination and splitting (two adults sacrifice themselves to create 3+ offspring), used in Stephen Baxter's "The We Who Sing".

Comment: I think this is an excellent example of ‘improvement’ being a very hard term to define. Widening the pelvis or having the child born sooner would improve childbirth success rates, but would adversely affect the mother’s gait or infant mortality rates/development..

Comment: @JoeBloggs absolutely. There's also questions about mother/child attachments, r/K reproductive strategies and a huge host of other things. But when you're designing something you're not limited to changing one thing at a time.

Comment: I am not sure this answer is correct, it just describes alternative strategies. The ultimate goal in reproduction would be to ensure survival of the offspring. Many species do not survive mating/childbirth and are well off. Humans have one of the smallest child-mortality-rates of all living things. Eggs are very fragile and the things that emerge from them are very fragile too ...

Comment: Nothing in the OP's question asks that we be able to discriminate between an evolved and designed creature. The example of the OP gives of not having the windpipe used for eating as well for example, that change wouldn't be obviously artificial. At least not without wider reference to the ecosystem and evolutionary path in which the creature exists.

Comment: Childbirth is a very good choice for something that could be designed better, but "laying eggs" is not really a simple change, nor likely to be optimal for human development. Moving the birth canal forward to the lower belly would be a much simpler and more effective change.

Comment: @Cyrus - Nice idea. In fairness my initial response was just "fix childbirth", and the OP asked for more so I panicked as biology is not really my area of expertise.

Comment: Fix childbirth by putting the exit in the abdomen, not forcing the poor child to thread-the-needle through a bone structure to get out! Kids nowadays need to have their skulls *crushed* just to make it out!

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of ways humans are obviously not "intelligently designed". A such designed humanoid would, for example:

1. Not have the genitals hanging outside the body
2. Have a much better arrangement of organs/spine. We obviously came from walking on all fours in an earlier form and the curved spine was there as a way to support the weight of hanging organs. Now most of us end up with back issues at some point.
3. No unnecessary organs (appendix)
4. No strange pathways for nerves (recurrent laryngeal nerve)
5. A bigger pelvis for the childbirth issue
6. The eyes could do with a redesign, amazing as they are. Possibly remove the blindspot and maybe increase the visible spectrum available outside RGB.

Other minor possibilities. Many non-human animals can safely eat things that would kill us...fix that! Birds can eat hot chillis with no irritation.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was thinking of, the spine in particular is an interesting one to consider. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Points 1) and 3) are actually important. E.g, keeping gametes cool/storing beneficial gut bacteria during infections

Comment: @Anonymous there is no evidence that the appendix stores 'beneficial gut bacteria' during infections. What function it has - mainly as sampling point for the immune system - could just as well be done otherwise (most animals do not have an appendix). Same for the genitals: if gametes were designed for a higher optimum temperature, genitals could easily be internal, and more protected.

Comment: @LSerni no evidence, but still strong indications. See [this article](https://www.newscientist.com/blog/shortsharpscience/2007/10/appendix-good-for-something-after-all.html) for instance.

Comment: Not have the genitals hanging outside the body -> Aren't testicles outside the body since sperms need a lower body temperature?

Comment: @Liquid yes, but an "intelligent" design would either include a circulatory feature that is capable of carrying away and venting excess heat (so perhaps the scrotum would just be skin flaps, "frills" or the like, that dissipate the heat), or as LSerni suggested, gametes that can tolerate the higher temperatures of being inside the body.

Comment: 'Birds can eat hot chillis with no irritation.' - what the point to eat them then :DDD, you wish to ruin good chunk of fun :D

Comment: Yes MolbOrg, I tend to agree, but it's an example. A bird can equally munch on deadly nightshade berries. 
Reminds me also of when (in the good old days) we left out an old cooker for the "rag and bone man" to pick up. Our dog got in it and found and ate a piece of festering meat. He later puked up, which included about a dozen maggots... Was right as rain after that...

Answer (score 3):

The concept of designing a single new species to be outright better than humans needs an understanding of what humans are bad at... but all the things we are bad at have benefits in other areas. so if we were designing a species, then it would probably be for the express purpose of of filling a role that humans are less suited for. humans are not very strong on average, but can be, the problem comes from frequently very strong people have less ability to finely turn their strength, if a Brain surgeon puts a a couple grams more pressure on the scalpel they could cut something important underneath the bit they're working on and kill someone, a body builder can exert a force much much larger than an average human, but often finds it harder to judge the difference between 2 and 4 grams of weight pushing against a knife. both sides have benefits and both have drawbacks, but not in their chosen environments.

It would drastically depend on what you were designing them for, imagine a world like that of Blade Runner (original as well as sequel) but in this world they are genetically engineered humans rather than synthetic ones

there would need to be a purpose to them, if you wanted ones that worked all day every day within a coal mine, you'd probably want better ability to filter particles out of the air they breath, similar to the way the nose does but on a faster scale, and they would need to be stronger, and therefore a stronger heart to deal with the stronger muscles, but would they need to be intelligent? probably not, otherwise they might start to question "why am i doing this instead of the regular humans."

On the flip side if you wanted to design the perfect Doctor or brain surgeon (that may or may not one day be in a car crash and become a wizard...) then strength loses out to very fine and precise motor control and high intelligence, but maybe an increased immune system to deal with being around sick people all the time.

Humans are prone to genetic change, height size shape and characteristics can change significantly every generation, this is what allowed humans to evolve the way they have, but this also makes genetic disorders much more common, admittedly this tends to happen more to the male side of the species then the female, as is more common in the entire animal kingdom.

if you where designing a new species of human specifically to work in and around Radioactive areas, you would probably make the chance of a genetic mutation a lot lower, this would drastically reduce the risk of Cancers and other serious health risks.

Answer (score 2):

I will address your initial question:

- *... are there any major defects in a human that you would expect not to exist if someone (or something) sat down to create the perfect humanoid?*

But let's formulate it in a bit different way:

- *Would we expect to be able to distinguish between designed and evolved life forms?*

Yes, but not necessarily.

A thing which may distinguish designed lifeform from evolved life form is that the first one is bound by the realm of physics, chemistry and other processes affecting or theories describing ontogenesis of the life form.

Naturally evolved life form is not only bound to all mentioned above, but also by inheritance of previous life forms and their particular restrictions and environmental factors which did shape them(their ancestors) in the evolution process before it split to another branch which is a root for the life from we may investigate.

In that regard evolved life form is more constrained in choosing or refurbishing its inheritance and has history, the history behind each element of its existence.

The designed life form is more free in that regard, creators more free to implement different solutions as they are not bound by the necessity of one solution to transit in another solution they may choose solutions from all possible solutions and not care if such thing could evolve naturally, are there some problems in that evolving, is there problem in transiting from one state to another. In that regard flame throwing dragons most likely to be engineered solution. There are tricks to implement, creative solutions to create a system in the way and fashion evolutions won't work.

To ignite a flame - is it possible to use electricity, sure, piezo elements, sure it possible. will it emerge naturally? Not likely - each change in natural selection should be useful or neutral, or at least not that bad. But better are those which get something for the change.

It may be more difficult to detect the creation if creators are copycats. The life from they created may look natural, as it has pieces of the puzzle which may have recognizable historical meaning.

But also we should then take look at the whole ecosystem they exist in. The first question would be to ask if they are part of it and its historical evolution records.
Then to see if their historical records belong to certain branch or multiple branches. Analyzing that data we can essentially tell if they are the probable result of the evolution of the ecosystem. Less probability, with a good understanding of the whole system and processes, higher are chances of their artificial creation.

As for specifics of improvements, it is a broad question and is opinion based part of it. Not all improvements are good in all environments, and they come with the cost of losing some options, because of fundamental limitations of blocks which are used.
As an example - fur is good for the cold environment, but excessive one is limiting mobility in a hot climate. There are incompatible solutions, and more adaptations we may willing to have, higher chances to hit the wall of those incompatibilities.

We may expect a wider spectrum of parameters of environment they can live in - but it is not granted.
And intelligent design may find different solutions around incompatible adaptations and each such trick decreases the probability to evolve naturally, so in a statistical sense, they can be well above average in the system, so we could suspect they are designed or it was a result of a unique situation. Taking into the account other data, we can say more precisely.

Things can be simple as everyone has blue eye's and 10-100 variations of the genes encoding that, depends how long in the past was the last correction.

very thing connection of certain aspects, as an example - not the blue eye, then died in a week or even born dead - it can be a sign of highly packed code, it can be a sign of design. Because naturally evolved life is more acceptable to mutations, more wiggle room for that, as it is a driving force for changes in their development and they are used to that.
So very high mortality rate among mutants and very rare mutations can be a sign. They may look as a diverse system, but it may be static in the diversity and may have a higher mortality rate in newborns than usually average in the ecosystem system.

So there are ways to detect tampering or creation. They aren't guaranteed.

Hardest would be a good creation of a whole system from scratch trying to mask the fact of creation. A system probably can be created to be indistinguishable from a naturally evolved system.
But we can test and try to determine how is the probability of the system to evolve naturally - there can be a difference in probabilities on the average in the galaxy, but we would not be able to catch the hand, just have a probability as a result.

as for improvement - add them more intelligence, the thing is not that much required for survivial, so hard to get too much of it in a natural way ...

Answer (score 2):

In our bodies of evolved creatures we have the so called [vestigial organs or functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestigiality), which are leftovers of previous features which we abandoned during the evolutionary path.

Some of these organs or functions are:

- The human caecum is vestigial, as often is the case in omnivores, being reduced to a single chamber receiving the content of the ileum into the colon.
- The plica semilunaris on the inside corner of the eye
- The formation of goose bumps in humans under stress is a vestigial reflex: its function in human ancestors was to raise the body's hair, making the ancestor appear larger and scaring off predators

With an analogy, you could compare them to a car having leftovers of the horse attaching bars used in the chariots from which it evolved.

In a properly designed system (and I assume an intelligent designed species is such), no leftovers should be present.

Comment: I like my goose bumps :DDD I mean they have important part in the intelligence and perception of things and expression of things

Answer (score -2):

Well, to answer that question, we will have to use our imagination a little.

So, let's pretend that humans created a "new type" of human being. An improved human. How would this human look like? But would they work in a fantasy world? No. If you use a thing from science fiction on a fantasy world, it will probably not work out. So, what could you do to "improve" the human body?

To create an "improved" human body, we will not only need to compare them to normal humans, but to mythical creatures too. But, if you think about it, what would you change? It's not like we are perfect, but I think that if something needs to be changed it would be almost completely aesthetic.

I think that if you want to change something about the human body in your fantasy world, you are the only person that can really decide.

Comment: `f you use a thing from science fiction on a fantasy world, it will probably not work out.` Why not? `But, if you think about it, what would you change? It's not like we are perfect, but I think that if something needs to be changed it would be almost completely aesthetic.` Why?

Comment: 'but I think that if something needs to be changed it would be almost completely aesthetic.' - actually a good point, we are grinded by evolution quite well. The rest are just perks or stuff we usually do not see.

Answer (score -2):

Intelligent design - no mouth. Mouth are not needed as food is digested through osmosis or photosynthesise (both ways working at once). You also don't need it for breathing as breathing through skin with ability of having gills-like skin. No speaking needed as telepathy would be a thing (something like Morse code by eyes but actually by changing your electro field). Also give the possibility to digest everything. Toadstool? No problem. No energetic value apart from that muscarine but that won't affect you.

why brain in skull? Keep much better eyes (like four of them) on a pole so they can see far and wide but keep brain in some extra cushion. Better even split brain functions and place their respective centers in different places in body. WITH extra replacement. So when one part of "brain" is destroyed it don't affect whole.

Regrown lost limbs. Like this is the worst. You're walking and suddenly elephant stomp on your foot. Man! So not cool. But you can easily cut it off as it will grow back in few weeks. You just need to osmosis some more energy and minerals.

Comment: both osmosis and photosynthesis are a large surface area to absorb the correct amounts of materials, human size and shaped animals do not have a large enough surface area they could point at the sun or submerge in whatever nutrients that are required. similary issues with Gills, but the eye pole thing could be of use in certain situtions and definately the limb regrowth

Comment: I doubt those changes would leave a generally human-looking being, as requested in the question.

Comment: @Liquid That's a thing with intelligent design isn't it? When you try to make something intelligent you don't always end up with something looking aesthetic.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKLY Not sure of that. Anyway, it doesn't make your current answer any less out-of-scope (imho, at least).